# Shiv'a Ushmonim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred eighty-seven?

### ?שבעה ושמונים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 287.

There are probably references to lazy gematria for this one scattered all over the place.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty-six entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: My upvote just gave you your 10000th reputation point. Mazel Tov!

Comment: That's odd. You seem to have lost a bunch of points.

Comment: @DoubleAA It looks like the fraud catching algorithm deleted all of a user's votes for my stuff. This isn't the first time this has happened. I suspect that some people who like this series vote it up consistently, and the fraud catcher sees that sort of consistent upvote as my stuff as potential sock-puppetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of chalakim (that don't add up to a full hour) in a non-leap year is 876; in a leap year it is 589. The difference between these two figures is 287.

(From an [allegory on the structure of the Jewish calendar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7301&pgnum=6))

Comment: +1. Just to clarify: That's the number of _chalakim_ in (respectively) twelve and thirteen months, _molad_ to _molad_, not in a calendar year.

Answer (score 5):

According to [*The American Jewish Year Book 5675*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Dp5KAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA218&dq=ooman#v=onepage&q=ooman&f=false), in [Uman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uman) in May of 1914, 287 people were tried and acquitted on a charge of demonstrating on [Beilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Mendel_Beilis)'s behalf.

Answer (score 3):

[Various sources](http://books.google.com/books?q=%22287+refugees%22+%22st+louis%22) say that Britain took 287 refugees from [the *St. Louis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_St._Louis) (although [others](http://books.google.com/books?q=%22288+refugees%22+%22st+louis%22) say 288).

Comment: I smell an answer for next time...

Comment: @DoubleAA: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13183. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

The number 7 appears 287 times in the Tanach.

( I looked it up in the concordance and googled it on Machon Mamre. (on Machon Mamre one of the 7 is listed as 3 score and 10 years, hence the original search gives only 286; searching in Hebrew does not work as it brings up on the variations where שבע appears in a word)

Incidentally 287 is a multiple of 7

Answer (score 1):

Gimtarya:

Afikoman

HaRambam

Pele Yoetz

Raui WeHagun

(as always these sources are from my Sefer "Gimtarikon).