# Shemona Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-eight?

### ?שמונה ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 298.

I wash my hands of anything to do with lazy gematria on this one.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-seven entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, It's where you take simplest notation of the number in Hebrew letters, use those letters to form a word, and then, if you're really lazy, just submit the fact that this number is the gematria of that word as an answer.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin [Indeed](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13182/shemona-ushmonim-umatayim-mi-yodeya).

Comment: This is actually one of the rare three-letter Hebrew combinations where every permutation is a word (and therefore there are six "lazy gematrias"): חצר, חרץ, צרח, צחר, רחץ, רצח.

Comment: @Alex, that could actually be an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/alport/archives/terumah69.htm) the [Ein Ya'akov](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ein_Yaakov), exactly 298 Kohanim could grasp the edges of the [Parochet](http://www.ou.org/torah/ti/5765/terumah65.htm) (partition-curtain) of the Temple at once, so that they could all participate in ritually immersing it. This number is, according to the Ein Ya'akov, exaggerated slightly as 300 in [Mishnayot Shekalim 8:5](http://www.chaver.com/Mishnah-New/Hebrew/Text/Seder%20Moed/Maschet%20Shekalim/Masechet%20Shekalim%20Perek%208.htm).

Answer (score 1):

[According to Meyer Waxman](http://books.google.com/books?id=APSOv3uEu3UC&pg=PA82&dq=didactic), *M'nachem* de Lonzano's *Derech Hachayim* has 298 verses. (However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Lonzano) calls it "*Derech Chayim*" and says it has 315 verses. I haven't checked, myself, how many verses it has.)

Comment: Wikipedia's source could be the author's magnum opus *Shetei Yadot*, [in which](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=6473&st=%u05d3%u05e8%u05da+%u05d7%u05d9%u05d9%u05dd+) he describes "Derech Chayim" as a "large poem of 315 verses." It's possible (just a guess) that an earlier version contained 298.

Answer (score -1):

In [1481](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Inquisition#The_start_of_the_Inquisition), 298 convicted heretics were burned at the stake in Seville, [according to Frank B. Goodrich](http://books.google.com/books?id=R44MAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA157&dq=convicted). His source seems to be Llorente [I guess [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juan_Antonio_Llorente)], *Añales de la Inquisicion*, I, 44. (However, I don't know whether these were Jews, Moslems, others, or some combination from among those groups.)